# Elastic Search with Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I ran the following docker compose script and I am expecting two nodes to be up, however this only one. There seems to be some obvious error.

Taken from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docker.html)

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.12
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.12
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/health

> 1598033352 18:09:12 docker-cluster green 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%

docker-compose ps

```
Name                   Command               State                Ports              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
elasticsearch    /usr/local/bin/docker-entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp
elasticsearch2   /usr/local/bin/docker-entr ...   Up      9200/tcp, 9300/tcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the issue. It seems both the containers are *somehow* not aware of each other and trying to create the clusters on their own.
I introduced delay with depends, it works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is up. But you need to map the port to some local unused port. Like you have mapped for first one `9200:9200`. Add the same for other one too like `8200:9200`. Then try hitting second one from local at 8200 port. It should work.

Comment: I didnt get what you mean by "up" , can you elaborate it further ?

Comment: Both the nodes are up and running.

Comment: that is NOT the issue , why the command gave different output then - 1598033352 18:09:12 docker-cluster green 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%